# $scope is not binding data in view

Tags: angularjs

I've been developing an e-commerce website and I am stuck at a point. I am using Stripe payment and all is working fine except data biding after token creation. Here is my controller

```
app.controller('shoppingCartController', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', 'stripe', '$window', function ($scope, $http, $sce, stripe, $window) {

        $window.Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_saiYYlyCNgO2yZq6Mu******');

        $scope.createToken = function () {
            var expire = $scope.master[0].expire.split('/');
            if ($scope.userDetail.$valid === true) {
                $window.Stripe.card.createToken({
                    number: $scope.master[0].card,
                    cvc: $scope.master[0].cvv,
                    exp_month: expire[0],
                    exp_year: expire[1],
                }, $scope.makepayment);

            }
        }

        $scope.makepayment = function (status, response) {
            if (response.error) {
                $scope.handleStripeCallback(response);
            } else {
                // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
                var data = {token: response.id, data: $scope.cartData};

                $http.post('make_payment', data).success(function (data) {
                    if (data.status) {
                        $scope.stripePaymentMessage = data.message;
                        $scope.stripePaymentMessageClass = "success";
                    } else {
                        $scope.stripePaymentMessage = data.message;
                        $scope.stripePaymentMessageClass = "danger";
                    }

                })
            }

        }

        $scope.handleStripeCallback = function (response) {
            //alert(response.error.message);
            $scope.stripChargeRequest = true;
            $scope.stripePaymentMessage = response.error.message;
            $scope.stripePaymentMessageClass = "danger";
        }



    }]);
```

In my view I am trying to handle error or success message with this code

```
<div ng-show="stripChargeRequest ">
    <div class="alert alert-{{stripePaymentMessageClass}}" role="alert" >
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        {{stripePaymentMessage}}
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is: stripChargeRequest angular variable contain true / false with normal scope binding but when I am trying to create a token by calling $scope.createToken() it not works. I guess I am forgetting something  in calling callback function $scope.makepayment(). Fortunately it is working in controller's scope. I can see error after stripe request in controller but it is not showing in view. Please suggest me the proper way of doing that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stripe callbacks are outside of angular so you need to use `$apply` to tell angular whenever you update the scope so it can run a digest to update the view

Example:

```
   $scope.handleStripeCallback = function (response) {
        //alert(response.error.message);
        $scope.stripChargeRequest = true;
        $scope.stripePaymentMessage = response.error.message;
        $scope.stripePaymentMessageClass = "danger";
        $scope.$apply(); // tell angular to update view
    }
```